# Weird memory access when calling DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, memory-leaks, windows-xp

I have previously asked a question regarding the use of a C library in Delphi ([How should I call this particular dll function in Delphi 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580361/how-should-i-call-this-particular-dll-function-in-delphi-6) ). With your help I was able to call it. Everything went great on some 20 PCs except that on one particular machine the function returns a random string. The machine is powered by a Celeron x86 processor, so it's not a 64/32 bit issue.

Can anyone help me identify why this is happening on that particular machine (but not on any other)?

Comment: Without any details, we cannot help you.

Comment: @David: What kind of details you need? I have created the function in a separate unit and I call it in a while block. I use the result in a dynamic SQL (to update the DB). So, on this particular machine, instead of a series of number I get 20 characters (length as expected), but not the result of the actual function call. Is there any particular way of describing the result that would help identifying the problem?

Comment: We have absolutely no idea what this function is. How on earth could we know why it is failing. You've provided no details, no code, no debugging diagnostics.

Comment: Sounds like the GetCid function in your CidGen32.dll is the culprit. Show the code.

Comment: A little bit dissapointed by the downvoting. 
But anyway. I have added a sample program (in delphi 6 but it should be easily portable to other versions) at https://www.dropbox.com/s/tk19j411iz28hfd/CidTest.zip.
This sample contains a program, the CidGen32.dll (whose code is not available to me) and 2 c++ redistributable dll's without which I would get an errors.

Comment: As it turns out, @mg30rg provided me with enough hints so I found out a solution/workaround. I noticed that these machines (where the dll / sample program did not work ) were all Win XP SP2. I upgraded to SP3 and everything worked just fine.
However, now I have new questions. Why doesn't it work on SP2? Is it related to the 2 c++ dlls? If they don't work as expected if they are just in the executable's folder, why don't they keep returning an error? Also, why don't they work if I just explicitely install C++ 2010 redistributable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to answer the question above we should know the OS running on the PC which fails to return an appropriate answer, and of the other ones. Without that I could only guess the cause of the problem. It might be:

- **An OS issue** - is the functionality provided by the running OS? (eg.: home edition windows versions does not support domains.) *(Try to run on other computers with the same OS (not only major version like 2000/Me/XP/Vista/7 etc. but edition like Home/Enterprise/Ultimate etc.))*
- **A memory management issue** - is the memory properly reserved for the called function? Some functions does return gibberish if the passed buffer is too small. *(Solution try to pass an extremely large buffer to see if the passed buffer still contains gibberish.)*
- **A calling convention issue** - have you checked if you use the proper calling convention? *(Solution make a debug build that uses stdcall, and try it on the non-working machine.)*
- **A functionality-related issue** - I do not know what is the function of this DLL. Might it fail gracefully? Is it a chance that the returned value only seems to be gibberish? *(Solution: check the documentation of the DLL file.)*
- **A Unicode-Ansi conversion error** - you might evaluate a Unicode string as Ansi or vica-versa without knowing it. *(solution: try using the* `GetCID(pWideChar(prm), pWideChar(uCID)` *convention to see if the error goes away))*
- **A HW error (fairly unlikely)** - in case of a RAM error all responses could be random. *(Soultion: Try running your program on an other computer with the exactly same configuration. If it runs well run a memory test on the pc with the wrong result.)*

For more exact help, I need more information **of the running computer:**

- OS (not only major version like 2000/Me/XP/Vista/7 etc. but edition like Home/Enterprise/Ultimate etc.)
- Processor class

**About the problem itself:**

- Some code sample which fails on the incriminated PC and runs well on other ones. 
  (Including memory reservation.)
- Screenshot of the CPU window before- and after the calling.
- Do not forget to show/describe what happens on the computers considered as well running the code! (It might also fail there, but the failure is hidden because of sudden conditions.)